# Reorder newick tree for specific two samples to be closest

Tags: tree, hierarchy, phylogeny

I have Newick tree
`((a:1, b:1):1, (c:1, d:1):1):1;`

I want specific two samples (a or b or c or d) to be as close to each other as possible

(of course without breaking the lineage of the tree)

For example, if I choose b and d

the result will be`((a:1, b:1):1, (d:1, c:1):1):1;`

It has to work on more complicated samples like

`((a:1, b:1):1, ((c:1, d:1):1, (e:1, f:1, g:1):1):1):1;`

If I choose b and f, the result has to be

`((a:1, b:1):1, ((f:1, g:1, e:1):1, (c:1, d:1):1):1):1;`

Order of g, e, c, d doesn't matter

Comment: What order time complexity are you looking for? How many nodes in your tree? Will brute force not suffice (is the number of nodes `N` > 10, for example?)

Comment: Also, why isn't the answer always 1? Does there exist a case where the two nodes cannot be placed adjacent to each other

Comment: @RyanZhang Above is the sample tree. The real tree will have more than 10.
So brute force will not be an option
Also, I don't think there will be an answer in case where two nodes cannot be placed as near as possible.
Because I have thought of pseudo-code for this.

Comment: @RyanZhang For example, to send 'f' to the leftmost category 
1. find the largest category containing f, and send the next lower category containing f to the left.
2. Repeat step 1. for the category one level below the above category.
I wanted to do this recursively. If my explanation is not good enough, sorry.

Comment: I have come up with a solution that involves recursion and is of complexity `O(N)`, for a tree with `N` nodes.

Comment: Are you looking for code or just an explanation of the algorithm?

Comment: @RyanZhang Code will be grateful. Thank you

Comment: I'll implement it in C++ for a larger bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `rotateConstr` from package `ape` mimics the intended behaviour with a bit of work. In theory, it should place the tips close to one another with a constraint of a partial list of the tip labels:

```
tr2 <- rotateConstr(tr, constraint = c("b", "f"))
```

In practice, the function performs best on a full list of ordered tip labels.

```
tr3 <- rotateConstr(tr, constraint = c("a", "b", "f", "e", "g", "c", "d"))
```